# Correct usage of g in a flask application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am new to flask, and am trying to figure out the correct way to use `g`, `request` and `current_app`. Also when not to use them!

A simple example of what I am trying to do:

```py
from db import DBClass

def route_handler():
  r = make_a_http_request()
  
  db = DBClass()
  db.store(r)
```

The above is how I would have approached this, import a db client and use it in my main handler.

What I have seen elsewhere is:

```py
### db.py
from flask import g

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = DBClass()
    return g.db

class DBClass:
  # ...


### route.py

from db import get_db

def route_handler():
  r = make_a_http_request()
  
  db = get_db()
  db.store(r)
```

Why would someone choose option 2? Are there any benefits to this approach from a structure, performance or safety perspective?

From what I understand `g` is new on each request, so storing things there is short lived.